# How to format a date in a given format

Tags: php, date, format

Hi all I need to format date exactly like this `Dienstag 28. September 2010, 15:00 Uhr` (German words), what is the best way? Thanks.

I guess I have to use date function but how to compose format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`date()` won´t be able to get you a German text, you will have to use [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

Example:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE");
strftime("%A %e. %B %Y, %H:%M Uhr", $your_date);
```

Comment: Thanks, even though strftime() was enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

[`setlocale`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) and [`strftime`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'de', 'ge');
echo strftime("%A %d %B %Y, %H:%M");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set your language in PHP with [setlocale()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) and then use strftime() with the corresponding format. That will allow you to get german output.